# Change pictiure on drag and drop with jquery, ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Change pictiure on drag and drop with jquery, ajax? 
I have two pictures I want to make it so when i drag one i can change the other to it. with jquery. and using php to cahnge it in mysql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check out my answer to [Enhancing a Jquery drag-and-drop demo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278845/enhancing-a-jquery-drag-and-drop-demo/5279300#5279300)  Basically you can change what is dragged by specifying a "helper."  The helper tells jquery what to show while dragging.  Then, there should be something you can override on drop.  I won't be any help for you on the php and mysql.